# Как убрать обводку при наведении курсора?

Tags: html, css

Есть такая конструкция:

```css
div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #919191;
    height: 100px;
    background: #F9FDFF;
}

div:hover {
    background: #ebf1f5;
}

div:last-child  {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Как убрать обводку снизу и сверху от блока, на который наведен курсор?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k9t8ufbf/1/

можно даже верхнюю перекрыть при желании, но там прозрачно не получится http://jsfiddle.net/k9t8ufbf/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/k9t8ufbf/4/

Answer (score 1):

Нужно для `div:hover` прописать `border: none;`